# I've made a https request to my api and drf pagiantion result next url contains http instead of https

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've a api which uses drf pagination , on hitting a https request the next url  part of my result contains http instead of https. How do I fix this?

My Pagination settings:

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000
```

I want it to work in such a way that if someone makes a http request it should return the next url containing http and if made https, next should have https.

Thank you,let me know if you guys need anything else to help me.

Comment: Could you check the value of `self.request.get_host()` in your view?

Comment: It's domain name without any http/https, e.g: api.example.com

Comment: Oh.. my bad. I actually meant `self.request.scheme`?

Comment: request obj has no attribute scheme

Comment: That's interesting. Which django version are you using?

Comment: its v 1.6.1 .
sorry Forgot to mention it

Comment: Please see if this helps you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header

Comment: @AKS You saved my day